# Perl: Permission Denied with scp_put of Net::OpenSSH

Tags: perl, ssh, scp, openssh

I'm trying to SCP a file into a remote machine using `Net::OpenSSH`'s `scp_put` function. Every time I run, I get the following error:

```
scp failed: scp failed: child exited with code 1 at copy_certs.pl line 32.
```

This is the code snippet where I attempt this operation:

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Exporter;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $user = "hello";
my $pass = "hello";
my $remote_path = "/hello_folder/ssl";

$host="10.221.33.4";
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $user, password => $pass, master_opts => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"]);    
$key_file = "certs/mykey.key";
$ssh->scp_put($key_file, $remote_path)
                or die "scp failed: " . $ssh->error;
```

When I perform this operation manually, I don't have any permission issues. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Enable debugging `$Net::OpenSSH::debug=-1` and attach here the output. It will show us the commands the module is running under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

If the remote host key has changed, there would be permission issues. Remove the RSA key of remote machine by running the following command - 
 "ssh-keygen -f "/.ssh/known_hosts" -R " and try again.

Comment: Tried it, it's not the problem.